# In C++, can you manually set the failbit of a stream? How?

Tags: c++, validation, inputstream

I am overloading the input stream operator for use with a Time class and would like to manually set the failbit of the input stream if the input doesn't match my expected time format (hh:mm). Can this be done? How?

Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, you can set it with `ios::setstate`, like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ios>

int main()
   {
   std::cout << "Hi\n";

   std::cout.setstate(std::ios::failbit);

   std::cout << "Fail!\n";
   }
```

The second output will not be produced because `cout` is in the failed state.

(An exception seems cleaner to me, but YMMV)

Comment: Yes, both input and output streams are derived from ios and ios_base

Comment: I think that setting the `failbit` is a very valid approach to reporting streaming errors as client code can use the same `if (in >> val) { /* success */ }` idiom that they can use for basic types.

Comment: Setting the fail bit is probably better than an exception as it mirrors how the standards types play with the stream.

Comment: Indeed. Typically you'd throw an exception from some place else, after discovering that the failbit has been set at this low level.

Comment: @JackLloyd, I usually write code like this for `operator >>(in, custom_type& c)`: `if ((in >> member1) && (in >> member2)) { c = custom_type{move(member1), move(member2)}; } else { in.setstate(std::ios::failbit); } return in;`. When written like this, you could embed `custom_type` in another object and read with a similar implementation (it stacks up nicely). The reason I like it, is because an 'if' is easier to write than a 'try/catch' block (for the client code) - it imposes less restrictions.