# Is there a way to check input data type using only basic concepts?

Tags: c++

I'm being challenged to find ways to perform tasks that usually require the use of headers (besides `iostream` and `iomanip`) or greater-than-basic C++ knowledge. **How can I check the data type of user input using only logical operators, basic arithmetic (+, -, *, /, %), if statements, and while loops?**

Obviously the input variable has a declared data type in the first place, but this problem is covering the possibility of the user inputting the wrong data type.

I've tried several methods including the `if (!(cin >> var1))` trick, but nothing works correctly. Is this possible at all?

#### Example

```
int main() {
    int var1, var2;
    cin >> var1;
    cin >> var2;
    cout << var1 << " - " << var2 << " = " << (var1-var2);

    return 0;
}
```

It's possible to input `asdf` and `5.25` here, so how do I check that the input aren't integers as expected, using only the means I stated earlier?

---

I understand this problem is vague in many ways, mostly because the restrictions are extremely specific and listing everything I'm allowed to use would be a pain. I guess part of the problem as mentioned in the comments is figuring out how to distinguish between data types in the first place.

Comment: What do you mean by checking the data type exactly. Obviously you can get input as string and then parse it.

Comment: How would you know if a number, without decimal point, is to be an integer or a double?

Comment: What types are you expecting and can you define their characteristics? That's the first step here.

Comment: @AKJ88 I can't even use parsing methods. I'm having trouble detailing exactly what I can and can't use here because it's very restricted. I just need to get user input and check, for example, that it's an integer and not a float.

Comment: The data type of user input is `char` (or possibly `unsigned char` on some uncommon platforms).

Comment: @twalberg If I define `int var1;` and then do `cin >> var1;`, `var1` is expected to be of type `int`.

Comment: @Adam Yes, but that's because the sequence of `char` values that were the input were *parsed* (interpreted) as a string representing an `int` value. The data type of the input is still just a sequence of `char`.

Comment: @twalberg That makes sense. So how come if I ask for two integers via `cin >> var1 >> var2;` and then input `5.25` as the first number, `var2` input is skipped and is automatically assigned a very large integer?

Comment: It's not assigned anything. It is left uninitialized because the stream is in a failed state. Reading from it is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using simple operations, although it might be a little difficult, for example the following function can be used to check if the input is a decimal number. You can extend the idea and check if there is a period in between for floating point numbers.

Add a comment if you need further help.

```
bool isNumber(char *inp){
    int i = 0;
    if (inp[0] == '+' || inp[0] == '-') i = 1;
    int sign = (inp[0] == '-' ? -1 : 1);
    for (; inp[i]; i++){
        if (!(inp[i] >= '0' && inp[i] <= '9'))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This looks pretty close to what I need, but I'm not allowed to use custom functions of any kind.

Comment: As other users mentioned, you can use the function's body in the `main` function. Everybody uses functions to just show the way it works, how you use it is up to you.

Comment: I'm also not allowed to use arrays. Is there any way to get around those here?

Comment: If you can use string, use it instead of char*.

Answer (score 0):

General checking after reading is done like this:

```
stream >> variable;
if (not stream.good()) {
    // not successful
}
```

This can be done on any [`std::ios`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/good/). It works for standard types (any numeric type, `char`, `string`, etc.) stopping at whitespace. If your `variable` could not be read, `good` returns false. You can customize it for your own classes (including [control over `good`'s return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640608/in-c-can-you-manually-set-the-failbit-of-a-stream-how)):

```
istream & operator>>(istream & stream, YourClass & c)
{
    // Read the data from stream into c
    return stream;
}
```

For your specific problem: Suppose you read the characters `42`. There is no way of distinguishing between reading it as 
 - an `int`
 - a `double`
as both would be perfectly fine. You have to specify the input format more precisely.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use any methods or customization like the ones you provided. It has to be done using only the means I stated at the beginning of my question.

Comment: You dont need cuatomizations for integers

Answer (score 0):

The standard library is not magic - you just have to *parse* the data read from the user, similarly to what the standard library does.

First read the input from the user:

```
std::string s;
cin >> s;
```

(you may use `getline` instead if you want to read a whole line)

Then you can go on parsing it; we'll try to distinguish between integer (`*[+-]?[0-9]+ *`), real number (`*[+-][0-9](\.[0-9]*)?([Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)? *`), string (`*"[^"]" *`) and anything else ("bad").

```
enum TokenType {
    Integer,
    Real,
    String,
    Bad
};
```

The basic building block is a routine that "eats" consecutive digits; this will help us with the `[0-9]*` and `[0-9]+` parts.

```
void eatdigits(const char *&rp) {
    while(*rp>='0' && *rp<='0') rp++;
}
```

Also, a routine that skips whitespace can be handy:

```
void skipws(const char *&rp) {
    while(*rp==' ') rp++;
    // feel free to skip also tabs and whatever
}
```

Then we can attack the real problem

```
TokenType categorize(const char *rp) {
```

first, we want to skip the whitespace

```
    skipws(rp);
```

then, we'll try to match the easiest stuff: the string

```
    if(*rp=='"') {
        // Skip the string content
        while(*rp && *rp!='"') rp++;
        // If the string stopped with anything different than " we
        // have a parse error
        if(!*rp) return Bad;
        // Otherwise, skip the trailing whitespace
        skipws(rp);
        // And check if we got at the end
        return *rp?Bad:String;
    }
```

Then, on to numbers, notice that the real and integer definitions start in the same way; we have a common branch:

```
    // If there's a + or -, it's fine, skip it
    if(*rp=='+' || *rp=='-') rp++;
    const char *before=rp;
    // Skip the digits
    eatdigits(rp);
    // If we didn't manage to find any digit, it's not a valid number
    if(rp==start) return Bad;
    // If it ends here or after whitespace, it's an integer
    if(!*rp) return Integer;
    before = rp;
    skipws(rp);
    if(before!=rp) return *rp?Bad:Integer;
```

If we notice that there's still stuff, we tackle the real number:

```
    // Maybe something after the decimal dot?
    if(*rp=='.') {
        rp++;
        eatdigits(rp);
    }
    // Exponent
    if(*rp=='E' || *rp=='e') {
        rp++;
        if(*rp=='+' || *rp=='-') rp++;
        before=rp;
        eatdigits(rp);
        if(before==rp) return Bad;
    }
    skipws(rp);
    return *rp?Bad:Real;
}
```

You can easily invoke this routine after reading the input.

(notice that here the string thing is just for fun, `cin` does not have any special processing for double-quotes delimited strings).

Comment: I'm not allowed to use custom functions of any kind.

Comment: You can inline them in the main function body, there's not anything special in `eatdigits` and `skipws` other than to avoid repeating the same stuff over and over.

Comment: Could you rewrite it using only the main function? I would have a hard time doing it myself.